# PHP ActiveRecord dynamic finder doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I've installed codeigniter with sparks, along with php-activerecord spark as instructed on getsparks.org

I've made model Item for Items data table

```
<?php 

Class Item extends ActiveRecord\Model {

}
```

and when I use

```
Item::all(array('conditions' => array('status = 0')))
```

everything goes fine, I'm getting all the items with status 0 via view (CI) (or via var_dump ).

By Using

```
Item::table()->last_sql;
```

gives me

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE status = 0
```

but when I use

```
Item::find_by_status(0); 

Item::table()->last_sql;
```

gives me

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `status`=? LIMIT 0,1
```

And I'm getting and error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Additional info:

table has this fiels:

```
id (int 11) primary key
name (varchar 15)
status (tiny int 1)
```

I'm using 
PHP version is 5.3.1

Comment: It seems that find_all_by_status(0) solved the problem

Comment: Using find_by_status(0) instead of find_all_by_status(0) makes error

Comment: You probably do need to use find_all_by instead of find_by because the latter would only return one record (I believe you want the whole collection)

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

using find_all_by_statys(0) instead of find_by_statys(0) because it returns many results instead of only one.